# 3D plotting of real life object to find Volume of Revolution

Tags: calculus, integration, graphing-functions, volume

I have an issue in a project where I am trying to find volume of a water pot through the use of double and triple integration. for that, I have to first plot the pot on a 3d graph but I am not really sure how it works or how it goes. Please help out. Moreover, performing integrals through the graph so I need to obtain equation of graph and also limits. Please help[Here is the picture of the water pot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UZxK.jpg)

With the help of the answer I plotted a circle and hyperbola reffereing to the points that I already had. I am not able to graph it on 3D platform, can someone help:2D graph:

[2D graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yz7OQ.png)

Comment: Why don't you fill it with water, and then pour the water out into a measuring cup?

Comment: @saulspatz bro that's like my verification method and this is my mathematics project so have to do it

Comment: Please consider its lateral projection onto a plane. Pick two different $2D$ curves that meet each other at the neck of the vessel and match the 2D projection (best approximation). Once you have finalized the curves, come back with the question on finding volume of revolution.

Comment: @Moo its like it but i need to graph in 3d to get the equation to apply double and triple integration

Comment: @MathLover can you please check if the volume of revolution with double integral can be applied to the below method of the idea of sphere and hyperboloid.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know if this is what you want but I tried modeling that pot using simple functions (a sphere and a hyperboloid) and it went something like this: [image: 2D Plot][image: 2D Plot drawn out] [image: 3D Plot]
I made a model in 2D and one in 3D, the 2D one is a slice of the 3D one, the equations are the ones seen in the pictures.
Those are just a sketch, I didn't actually check if the sphere intersects with the hyperboloid or not, and the values I used were chosen by eye, if this is what you're looking for I can help you finding good values for those constants afterwards.
Also, the pot on the picture is a bit more flat than a sphere, I could also change that on our model if you'd like, using something like a parabola or so.
What are your toughts? Does this help or is this not what you're looking for?
(If this doesn't help, you can also try out fourier series, I don't actually know how to model that with those but I know its possible, its just a matter of research).

Comment: Hey Carlos thank you so much for the answer but I have some real time values for the pot on a 2d graph. I think your method is valid. Could you please check if you are able to make 3D graph through those points and also is it that the hyperboloid and sphere intersect because I am going to use double integration afterwards so they need to intersect. I have thought to revolve it around x axis. These are the points: X,Y:
A:0 3
B: 4.833467 5.871251
C: 8.376429 4.476384
D: 9.324939 4.030026
E: 10.18976 4.560076
F: 11.50093 5.750000
G: 12.28206 4.253206

Comment: This is what I was talking about in my comment earlier. very good attempt. +1 from me.

Comment: @MathLover so we can apply double integration to the hyperboloid and sphere right to get the volume of revolution?

Comment: @jack no we take the circle and hyperbola the way shown in the answer and revolve, it will give the volume. But you did not mention earlier that you had specific coordinates - if that is so those points need to be plotted first and see which is the best fitting curve.

Comment: Is there a way that we try to employ the sphere and hyperbola with our coordinates and then apply double integral formula for 3d graph. Can that be possible

Comment: @Carlos Roxo any findings if you are able to make the hyperbola and sphere according to the points

Comment: Ok, with those points it may get easier, I would just like to know (if you can find them) the points with y=0 at both sides. https://imgur.com/gallery/MbxtEjh This picture ilustrates it, for better understanding.

Comment: @CarlosRoxo They are -0.6902066467741 and 12.7842100137437

Comment: Ok, i tried to plot it and it went real nice, the function is this one h(x)=-0.000004821832 x^(8)+0.0002047765391 x^(7)-0.003532482 x^(6)+0.0322776953 x^(5)-0.1708897 x^(4)+0.541598 x^(3)-1.13015564 x^(2)+2.08143 x+2.902511, (a bit big but just because the constants are big too). The plot looks like this: https://imgur.com/a/3oT4r8c. I'll try to plot it in 3d too if Im able to find out how to do it.

Comment: Ok, my method isn't perfect yet, but I was able to plot it like this: https://imgur.com/gallery/QgCodTY, I used parametric functions if you're interested in trying too.

Comment: @CarlosRoxo  can you helpp me out finding the volume i am having problem with the limits

Comment: Yea sure, what limits do you need to find?